# SASS Invalid CSS error on Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to use http://startbootstrap.com/stylish-portfolio in my rails app however I'm getting the following error in my stylish-portfolio.css.scss.erb file:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Invalid CSS after "body ": expected selector or at-rule, was "{"
```

This is my css file:

```
@import 'bootstrap'

/* Global Styles */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.vert-text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.vert-text h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 4.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

...

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the file producing the error...

Comment: That looks like the CSS file for FontAwesome. Could you check the actual contents of `stylish-portfolio.css.scss.erb` and maybe edit the post?

Comment: Note to future readers: the CSS is now the correct one, disregard the above two comments. :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing a semicolon in the `stylish-portfolio.css.scss.erb` file, maybe after an SCSS variable definition?

[Here's the original CSS file](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/blob/v1.0/templates/stylish-portfolio/css/stylish-portfolio.css) I assume you are basing this on, maybe you want to do a `diff` between that and yours to determine what has changed.

---

**Edit:** Yup, apparently there is a missing semicolon after the first line. The `@import` statement

```
@import 'bootstrap'
```

should instead be

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

since you are using the `.scss` extension. You can omit the semi-colon if you are using the `.sass` extension.

Comment: Stupid mistake, posted the wrong file here. Actually I was missing a semi-colon in my stylish-portfolio.css.scss file. Anyways I will edit the question, thanks!

Comment: On another notice if you could give me a hand on another error I'm having I would very much appreciate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142113/asset-pipeline-undefined-variable-sass). I've been googling for a long time now and still can't find a solution.

Comment: To be clear: the issue is that it is specifically the @import 'bootstrap' line that needs to have a semi-colon at its end. The comment on the question about "that's not the file producing the error" appears to be related to some previous snippet that the asker posted, but it made me misinterpret "after" in this answer to mean, "somewhere lower in the file".   Docs here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass

Comment: Thanks Fritz, I tried to edit the answer to clarify this a bit.

Comment: Link to the original CSS file is dead.

Comment: Thanks Ege, I edited the link to point to an older version of the file.