# Asset Pipeline Undefined Variable SASS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've been trying to use http://startbootstrap.com/stylish-portfolio and after downloading all files and copying to the directory I'm getting the following error on the partial _bordered-pull:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".
```

However the variable is defined and I'm importing (or at least trying) the partial.

My assets/stylesheets directory is the following:

```
--application.css.scss
--bootstrap.css.scss
--font-awesome.css.scss.erb
--stylish-portfolio.css.scss
--|font-awesome
  --_bordered-pulled.css.scss
  --...(other partials)
  --font-awesome.css.scss
```

Application.css.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import 'font-awesome/font-awesome';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome';
@import 'stylish-portfolio';
```

Font-awesome.css.scss

```
/*!
 *  Font Awesome 4.0.3 by @davegandy - http://fontawesome.io - @fontawesome
 *  License - http://fontawesome.io/license (Font: SIL OFL 1.1, CSS: MIT License)
 */

@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "path";
@import "core";
@import "larger";
@import "fixed-width";
@import "list";
@import "bordered-pulled";
@import "spinning";
@import "rotated-flipped";
@import "stacked";
@import "icons";
```

_bordered-pulled.css.scss

```
// Bordered & Pulled
// -------------------------

.#{$fa-css-prefix}-border {
  padding: .2em .25em .15em;
  border: solid .08em $fa-border-color;
  border-radius: .1em;
}

.pull-right { float: right; }
.pull-left { float: left; }

.#{$fa-css-prefix} {
  &.pull-left { margin-right: .3em; }
  &.pull-right { margin-left: .3em; }
}
```

Is it a syntax error or did I setup my asset pipeline wrong?

_variable.css.scss
https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap/blob/master/templates/stylish-portfolio/font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: Can you show us `variables.css.scss` as well? I'm guessing that's where you are defining the variable?

Comment: Just updated the question

Comment: Very strange. Are you sure no semicolons are missing? ;) I would debug it further by setting `$fa-css-prefix` directly in `_bordered-pulled.css.scss` and see if it works, then trying out other variables from `_variables.css.scss` to narrow down if any of them are in scope. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: On another note, check out the [bootstrap-sass](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass) and [font-awesome-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/font-awesome-rails) gems. You may be better off using them than copying the files manually.

Comment: When I add "@import 'variables';" on my partials I do not get an error. However I'm trying to find another way around instead of adding manually @import to all files.

Comment: can someone help me on this please..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885509/bundle-exec-rake-assetsprecompile-throws-font-awesome-related-issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do the following:

> Open your project's font-awesome/less/variables.less or font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss and edit the @fa-font-path or $fa-font-path variable to point to your font directory.

Source: fontawsome's documentation

http://fontawesome.io/get-started#custom-less

Comment: Not able to fix with this, can you please check this out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885509/bundle-exec-rake-assetsprecompile-throws-font-awesome-related-issue

Answer (score 2):

Try checking how you are precompiling assets. Check initializers/assets.rb (or it may be environments/production.rb for you) to make sure you are precompiling assets in a friendly way, like this:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*.js", "*.scss", "*.jpg", "*.png"]
```

I was having this same error when it was

```
config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.png/,/.*\.ico/,/.*\.jpg/,/.*\.js/,/.*\.scss/]
```

Comment: I think we don't need to precompile assets in development env