# not able to push the app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, font-awesome

I am trying to put my app to heroku but I am getting an issue.

> remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".

I am using **font-awesome-rails**.

I am doing `git push staging master` after following all the steps properly.

**Edit: variables.less**

```
@fa-font-path:        "/assets/font-awesome/fonts";
//fa-font-path:        "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/fonts"; // for referencing Bootstrap CDN font files directly
@fa-css-prefix:       "fa";
@fa-version:          "4.2.0";
@fa-border-color:     #eee;
@fa-inverse:          #fff;
@fa-li-width:         (30em / 14);
```

Please help!

Comment: Please post the complete log.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asset Pipeline Undefined Variable SASS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142113/asset-pipeline-undefined-variable-sass)

Comment: does it work if you remove the variable?

Comment: didn't try that options as yet

Comment: @Grammakov It is not working even after that. tried other stuffs as well. Still get this $fa-css-prefix probmlem while I do bundle exec

Comment: how about changing fa with "fa"?

Comment: It was that way only, I missed it there in the question. Same issue

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Open your project's font-awesome/less/variables.less or font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss and edit the @fa-font-path or $fa-font-path variable to point to your font directory.

Read more on it here

http://fontawesome.io/get-started#custom-less

Comment: Please check my updated question. I have added snippet from variables.less