# bundle exec rake assets:precompile throws font-awesome related issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I am getting error while doing `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/XkqexDjP) complete error I am getting on terminal while I hit the above command.

Here's my **variables.less** code snippet

```
@fa-font-path:        "assets/font-awesome/fonts";
@fa-css-prefix:       "fa";
@fa-version:          "4.2.0";
@fa-border-color:     #eee;
@fa-inverse:          #fff;
@fa-li-width:         (30em / 14);
```

Here's my **font-awesome.css** snippet

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?  v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

 .fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
```

Not able to figure out the issue on this. Can someone please help me here.

Thanks

Comment: show your application.css

Comment: Try this @import "font-awesome.min";

Comment: `  *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome `

This is what I have in my application.css

Comment: have already tried that @ChitrankSamaiya 

Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".

This is still the same

Comment: change your application.css to application.css.scss

Comment: not getting the error but the  bundle exec rake assets:precompile is just stuck on next line. :-/

Comment: I am not clear what you are saying?

Comment: my bad, It threw me this error now

Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome.min.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80750/discussion-between-chitrank-samaiya-and-suraj).

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? i have the same problem..