# Sass::SyntaxError after @import "bootstrap" in application.css.scss

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

My rails (with bootstrap-sass gem) application.css.scss looks like this:

```
/*
 * ...boilerplate application.css.scss comments
 *= require_tree .                                                              
 *= require_self                                                                
 */                                                                             
@import 'bootstrap'

.container-fixed {                                                              
  margin: 0 auto;                                                               
  max-width: 970px;                                                             
}
```

Viewing any page gives me a Sass:SyntaxError like this `Invalid CSS after "...ort 'bootstrap'": expected selector or at-rule, was ".container-fixed {"`. I don't see a problem with the `.container-fixed` snippet. [Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140438/sass-invalid-css-error-on-rails) I see that this error can be caused by a file imported before the line that Sass complains about. However, there is no other CSS in this project (apart from bootstrap itself). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after your import.

Comment: Also, rename your application.css to application.css.scss if you haven't.

Comment: You mean the import line should read @import 'bootstrap'; ?

Comment: @Vageesh my typo, it is named application.css.scss

Comment: Doh! the docs are quite clear. My mistake

Comment: @Cinammon if you add an answer I'll delete mine and mark yours correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per Cimmanon's comment, the issue is fixed by adding a semi-colon at the end of the @import line, as shown in the [bootstrap-sass docs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#sass).